# Global NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I need to create an NSString, so I can set its value in one class and get it in another. How can I do it?

Comment: Will the string ever need to be changed during runtime?

Comment: All the solutions for global strings and singletons just because the question mentioned it. It's perfectly possible to do this with properties of an object if the question is just about creating / changing a string in restricted usage. Notifications is another way. KVO is another way. - You could even use delegation. There isn't enough information in the question to allow a considered answer to be provided.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you write:

```
NSString *globalString = @"someString";
```

anywhere outside a method, class definition, function, etc... it will be able to be referenced anywhere. (it is global!)

The file that accesses it will declare it as external

```
extern NSString *globalString;
```

This declaration signifies that it is being accessed from another file.

Answer (score 6):

Make it a global variable.

In one file in global scope:

```
NSMutableString *myString = @"some funny string";
```

In the other file:

```
extern NSMutableString *myString;
```

Answer (score 6):

**Global NSString Variable for Complete iPhone Project/Apps**

For Declare/Define/Use a global variable follow these easy steps:-

1. Create a NSObject File with named "GlobalVars.h and .m" or as u wish
2. Declare your global variable in GlobalVars.h file after #import and before @implementation like-

   extern NSString *Var_name;
3. initialize it in GlobalVars.m file after #import and before @implementation like-

   NSString *Var_name = @"";
4. Define its property in AppDelegate.h File

   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Var_name;
5. synthesize it in AppDelegate.m File like-

   @synthesize Var_name;
6. Now where you want to use this variable (in .m file) just import/inclue GlobalVars.h file in that all .h files, and you can access easily this variable as Globally.
7. Carefully follow these Steps and it'll work Surely.

Comment: It works! But I needed to remove the steps 4 and 5. I don't know why, but worked.

Answer (score 3):

If you're creating a global `NSString` variable, you should use probably use a class method.

In `MyClass.h`:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {}
     + (NSString *)myGlobalVariable;
     + (void)setMyGlobalVariable:(NSString *)val;
@end
```

In `MyClass.m`:

```
@implementation MyClass
    NSString *myGlobalVariable = @"default value";

    + (NSString *)myGlobalVariable {
        return myGlobalVariable;
    }

    + (void)setMyGlobalVariable:(NSString *)val {
        myGlobalVariable = val;
    }
@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember that you should keep memory allocation and freeing in mind. This is not the same thing as a global int value - you need to manage the memory with any NSObject.

Repeatedly just setting the global to new strings will leak. Accessing through threads will create all manner of issues. Then there is shutdown where the last string will still be around.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a singleton. A good article that discusses this is [Singletons, AppDelegates and top-level data.](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html)

Additional information on a singleton class is at [MVC on the iPhone: The Model](http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=1969)